# Flink metrics - number of records count within metric interval

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Flink version 1.9.1. We would like to get the number of records processed by a particular subtask in a particular period. The number of records out gives the total number of records out till then. Is there a way to get the total number of records processed within that metric interval.

Answer (score 0):

Flink also registers a metric called `numRecordsOutPerSecond` which is the rate of the produced records. By integrating this value over any interval you should be able to obtain the rate over this interval.

Answer (score 0):

Flink supplies metrics reporters for several popular metrics systems, such as Prometheus, and InfluxDB, that provide powerful query engines for computing all sorts of aggregate statistics based on the metrics they get from Flink.